# mysql select groupby 2 columns

Tags: mysql

MySQL

Table Messages

```
    | fromuser | toUser | message | time
    | 1        | 2      | Hi?     | +1
    | 2        | 1      | Hello!  | +2
    | 1        | 3      | There?  | +3
    | 3        | 1      | Yes     | +4
    | 2        | 3      | Hey     | +5
    | 3        | 2      | Sup?    | +6
    | 1        | 2      | :)      | +7
    | 1        | 4      | thanks  | 
    | 4        | 1      | welcome |
```

I need a query for latest message

Closest I got is

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE fromUser=1 OR toUser=1 ORDER BY time DESC) AS msg GROUP BY fromUser,toUser
```

Result:

```
| fromuser | toUser | message | time
| 2        | 1      | Hello!  | +2
| 1        | 3      | There?  | +3
| 3        | 1      | Yes     | +4
| 1        | 2      | :)      | +7
| 1        | 4      | thanks  | 
| 4        | 1      | welcome |
```

it returns the latest from and latest to.

What I want is

```
    | fromuser | toUser | message | time
    | 3        | 1      | Yes     | +4
    | 1        | 2      | :)      | +7
    | 4        | 1      | welcome |
```

Latest of from and to of user1, like how a list of chats work.

Comment: What is '+'? Get rid of it

Comment: not actual data.. just show which 1 is later..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP is looking for the latest message from each dialogue within which a given user participates.

There's a probably a more elegant solution, but here's one way...

Note that my dataset has a surrogate PK...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(fromuser INT NOT NULL
,toUser INT NOT NULL
,message VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,message_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,2,'Hi?',1),
(2,1,'Hello!',2),
(1,3,'There?',3),
(3,1,'Yes',4),
(2,3,'Hey',5),
(3,2,'Sup?',6),
(1,2,':)',7),
(1,4,'thanks',8),
(4,1,'welcome',9);

SELECT a.* FROM my_table a
JOIN 
(
SELECT MAX(message_id) message_id FROM
(
SELECT toUser correspondent,message,message_id FROM my_table WHERE fromuser = 1
UNION
SELECT fromuser,message,message_id FROM my_table WHERE touser = 1
) x
GROUP BY correspondent
) b
ON b.message_id = a.message_id;

+----------+--------+---------+------------+
| fromuser | toUser | message | message_id |
+----------+--------+---------+------------+
|        1 |      2 | :)      |          7 |
|        3 |      1 | Yes     |          4 |
|        4 |      1 | welcome |          9 |
+----------+--------+---------+------------+
```